# sqlite3 database query in python

Tags: python, sqlite, database-connection

I tried performing a search query from the backend of an app I'm working and I got the response below:

**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "backend.py", line 30, in search
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM PlanInfo WHERE Location=?", self.NmRqst.text)
ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type**

I have the code below:

```
def connectfile(self):
    conn = sqlite3.connect("TestTrace.db")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PlanInfo (Plan Number TEXT, Tracing Number TEXT, Submitted By TEXT, "
        "Location TEXT)")
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

def search(self):
    conn = sqlite3.connect("TestTrace.db")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM PlanInfo WHERE Location=?", self.NmRqst.text)
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    conn.close()
    return rows
```

**self.NmRqst.text** is the QLineEdit that accepts the user input for database query...

Feel free to correct the question as you deem fit!

I have edited the lines of code,

```
def connectfile(self):
    conn = sqlite3.connect("TestTrace.db")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PlanInfo (Plan_Number TEXT, Tracing_Number TEXT, Submitted_by TEXT, "
        "Location TEXT)")
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

def search(self):
    conn = sqlite3.connect("TestTrace.db")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM PlanInfo WHERE Location=?", str(self.NmRqst.text,))
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    conn.close()
    return rows
```

...and I got the following error:

**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "backend.py", line 30, in search
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM PlanInfo WHERE Location=?", str(self.NmRqst.text,))
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 64 supplied.**

Comment: It's unclear what API self.NmRqst.text / QLineEdit is. Try to pass in a simple string. If that works, your question is about getting a string out of self.NmRqst.text. Maybe it can just be converted to str.

Comment: Could you show us the output of `print(type(self.NmRqst.text))` before the failing `execute`? Thanks.

Comment: I bet it boils down to making `self.NmRqst.text` a sequence in the call to `execute()`, like so `(self.NmRqst.text,)`.

Comment: @de1, I'll try that, thanks

Comment: @Florian Weimer, I'm new to python, I intend to show the out on a QTableWidget named **InfoDsp** but I don't know to go about that yet, any help will be appreciated, thanks...

Comment: @shmee, I'll try that too, thanks

Comment: Are you trying to use spaces in your column names or something?

Comment: @Shawn, yes I am

Comment: Why are you doing that string conversion with your parameter? The execute call is supposed to look like this `cur.execute("SELECT * FROM PlanInfo WHERE Location=?", (self.NmRqst.text,))`. That is, if `self.NmRqst.text` is a string. If not, please do as @FlorianWeimer suggested and put `print(type(self.NmRqst.text))` in your code above the `cur.execute()` with the SELECT statement and show us what it prints when you run it.

Comment: It gives the **output** and error below:    **<class 'builtin_function_or_method'>**  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "backend.py", line 40, in search
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM PlanInfo WHERE Location=?", (self.NmRqst.text,))
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.

Comment: Which means, that `self.NmRqst.text` is a function of some sort. Which in turn means that you should probably call it: `cur.execute("SELECT * FROM PlanInfo WHERE Location=?", (self.NmRqst.text(),))`. Please read the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtWidgets/QLineEdit.html#PySide2.QtWidgets.PySide2.QtWidgets.QLineEdit.text) of the technology you are using.

Comment: @shmee, you are a life saver! It worked perfectly well!!! Thanks in a million ways a million times